# Transform of ELMAH string when publishing to production server name not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, elmah

I am running Visual Studio 2010, using an ASP.Net forms application.I am trying to transform XMl on build but it is not working.

In my config section I have the following:

```
 <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionString="Data Source=TestServer;Initial Catalog=OnlineApplication;Trusted_Connection=True" />
    <errorMail from="emhelp@server.edu" to="person@test.com" subject=" Exception" async="true" smtpserver="smtpgate.server.edu" />
```

I am trying to get it the ELMAH server name to transform when I publish to production via web.config.production xml transformation. All of my other settings for the app settings and connection strings work fine.
I have the following in my web.production.config:

```
    <add type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah"
         connectionString="Server=ProductionServer;Initial Catalog=OnlineApplication;Integrated Security=True"
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(type)"/>
</elmah>
```

It doesn't complain but it also does't transform the text. What do I need to change to make the file transform on build/publish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since is only one `errorLog` tag, you can use `Replace` instead of `SetAttributes` with a locator. Also note that you have to use the actual tag name, not `<add>`.

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah"
     connectionString="Server=ProductionServer;Initial Catalog=OnlineApplication;Integrated Security=True"
     xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```